# Extract Test from String Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    var a = "Usd:12.34";
```

Umm...so a is a variable and what i want is to extract the word Usd and assign it to var b in Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string literal on the `:` character and retrieve the first element in the array.

```
var a = "Usd:1234";
var b = a.split(":")[0];
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CXdqc/

Answer (score 1):

If there will always be `:` as separator you could use the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method:

```
var a = "Usd:12.34";
var b = a.split(':')[0];
```

Here we are splitting the text using the `:` separator and taking the first element in the resulting array. You could perform additional error checking to ensure that the string was in the correct format.